# How do I pass custom ArrayAdapter Object between Intents with serialization

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, serialization

**Background**:
I am just starting with Android and I have learned about Intents and `ListView`. I have am creating a simple app where a user enter some information and that information is added into ListView. For this I have created a ListView in my MainActivity class. Created a class for Objects named `User` and created Custom ArrayAdapter `UserAdapter.` Both of my classed `User` and `UserAdapter` implements `Serializable` marker interface. Now whenever someone click on button from `MainActivity` class to add data a new Intent opens and takes input from that intent and return back to `MainActivity` intent. I am passing `UserAdapter` Object between intents.

**Problem:**
Now the problem Adapter Object is showing is not working in next Intent.

**Code:**
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //blah blah blah ...
        // Main code starts here

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        ArrayList<User> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter(this, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), AddUser.class);
                intent.putExtra("adapter", adapter);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
    //blah blah blah ...
}
```

UserAdapter.java

```
public class UserAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> implements Serializable {
    public UserAdapter(Context context, Collection<User> arrayList) {
       //call ArrayAdapter's constructor
       //context, layout, collection
        super(context, 0, (ArrayList<User>)arrayList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View obj, ViewGroup parent) {
        User user = getItem(position);
        if(obj == null) {
            obj = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_layout, parent, false);
        }
        TextView name = (TextView) obj.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        TextView adress = (TextView) obj.findViewById(R.id.user_address);
        name.setText(user.getUserName());
        adress.setText(user.getUserAddress());
        return obj;
    }
}
```

User class also implements Serializable and I don't think you need that class implementation but if you want I can add that here.

Now My Second Activiy class 
AddUser.java

```
public class AddUser extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_user);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String address = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.address)).getText().toString();
                String contact = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact)).getText().toString();
                String college = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.college)).getText().toString();
                User user = new User(name, address);
                user.setCollege(college);
                user.setContact(contact);
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                UserAdapter adapter = (UserAdapter)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Adapter");
                adapter.add(user);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
02-20 18:35:37.264 12074-12074/com.example.deepanshu.customadapter3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.deepanshu.customadapter3, PID: 12074
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object (name =com.example.deepanshu.customadapter3.UserAdapter)
        at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2380)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2203)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getSerializable(BaseBundle.java:988)
        at android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(Bundle.java:845)
        at android.content.Intent.getSerializableExtra(Intent.java:5256)
        at com.example.deepanshu.customadapter3.AddUser$2.onClick(AddUser.java:47)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4789)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19881)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
        Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: android.widget.ArrayAdapter; IllegalAccessException
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.resolveConstructorClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:712)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.newInstance(ObjectStreamClass.java:673)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
        at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2378)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2203) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getSerializable(BaseBundle.java:988) 
        at android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(Bundle.java:845) 
        at android.content.Intent.getSerializableExtra(Intent.java:5256) 
        at com.example.deepanshu.customadapter3.AddUser$2.onClick(AddUser.java:47) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4789) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19881) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

You cannot checkout code [here](https://github.com/Deepanshu2017/Android_learning/tree/master/CustomAdapter3)

Also check issue in my Github profile too.

Comment: if you are opening a 2nd activity to insert data that will be inserted in the adapter in activity1, then start the 2nd activity  "forResults" and add the new item in the list

Comment: Yes I can do 'startActivityForResult()' or with Parcelable but I want to fix the above code.

Comment: I would rather recommend you to use startActivityForResult method while loading AddUser intent .and then you will pass only the newly added user object to the invoking intent.

Comment: Send the adapter for another activity is not correct. Use  startActivityForResult to get your values then result method is called.

Comment: So we cannot send adapter object?
PS: I have a working code with startActivityForResult but I am still interested in work around with above code

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass your custom `ArrayAdapter` or any other `BaseAdapter/ArrayAdapter` object in intent.

As you know that to pass any object in intent it should be either `Parcelable` or `Serializable`.

As per documentation of Serializable interface https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html

> The serialization mechanism encodes an object's class name, the names
>   of its non-transient fields (including non-public fields), and the
>   values of all of those fields.

Here, when you implement `Serializable` interface to your custom `ArrayAdapter` class, it does not actually gets the ability of  Serialization, because when you implement `Serializable` interface, all fields takes part in the Serialization process.

**But [android.widget.ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) class itself does not implement `Serializable` interface.**
So indirectly your custom `ArrayAdapter` which inherited from `android.widget.ArrayAdapter`, is also not `Serializable`.

And considering your example, as mentioned in the comments, please call the intent with `startActivityForResult()` to get the object to be added to your custom adapter.

Hope so you can understand this!

Read more about Serialization process!